# RequireJS module with web worker in library

Tags: javascript, requirejs, web-worker

As with most use cases of web workers, I've got a piece of code that can potentially take a while to run - it builds up an Excel worksheet based on a bunch of data. But, as workbooks can have multiple worksheets, it'd behove me to try to run them in parallel (and besides that, as large as they can get, it'd be nice not to have a frozen UI for a second or two on a 10k+ row file).

Anyway, the problem is that since this is a library, I want the end user to have to do as absolute little as possible. I already know that I can pass over the absolute path to the modules that are required (via require.toUrl), as well as all of the data that is needed to build up these xml structures.. and I know I can pass the structures back easily enough. Unfortunately though I have no idea where requirejs is coming from.

So, does requirejs have any way of referencing its own path? Assuming that it doesn't, would it be appropriate to 'require' that a user add a parameter on requirejs' config telling where the requirejs file is? Or should I instead have that as a required param for the library itself? Or perhaps adding an ID to the script that is pulling in requirejs and reading the src off of that?

Basically, what's the least intrusive way that this can be done, while not painting either myself or my users into a corner.

Comment: Did you ever decide on a solution to this? I am working on something similar and we get our requireJS from CDN, so I'd rather keep that configuration in one spot.

I was thinking of going the route of forcing the user to add a requirePath config to requireJS config that we can then pass to the web worker.

Comment: That's kind of the route I went. If requirejs didn't have a property set on it that had its path, I would do something like $("script[src~='require.js'], script[src~='require.min.js']").first().attr('src'), which basically covers the two main file names. Sorry, code isn't in front of me at the moment.